How to get the root relation id in a nested relationship
Product::with(['sub_products' => function ($query) {
  $query->with(['product' => function ($subQuery) use ($query) {
    $subQuery->with(['sub_products' => function ($nestedQuery)  use ($query) {
      $nestedQuery->where('main_product_id', $query->getModel()->id); // top product condition
      $nestedQuery->with(['product']);
    }]);
  }]);
}]);

Here $query->getModel()->id is not returning the top product id.
How can I get the top relation ID inside the nested relation?

table: products:
id,
name;


table: product_relations:
id,
main_product_id,
parent_product_id,
child_product_id;

public function sub_products()
{
  return $this->hasMany(ProductRelation::class, 'parent_product_id');
}

I tried various ways but everywhere it ask to pass $main_product_id statically.
Thanks.

The tooltip from tag sql says: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL."
